# CustomTaskChange gets actually executed when called updateSQL

Tags: java, liquibase

I have a `CustomTaskChange` in Liquibase (besides other ChangeSets). 
I want my application to show the SQL of all ChangeSets before actually executing it. In my understanding, `updateSQL` should preview the SQL and execute nothing. A `CustomTaskChange` however gets executed right away. I would have expected that the `CustomTaskChange` is ignored, when calling `updateSQL`.

The ChangeSet:

```
<changeSet id="2" author="clu">
    <comment>Print out 'helloworld'.</comment>
    <customChange class="path.to.HelloWorldUpdate">
</customChange>
</changeSet>
```

The CustomTaskChange:

```
public class HelloWorldUpdate implements CustomTaskChange {
    @Override
public void execute(Database database) throws CustomChangeException {
    System.out.println("HELLO WORLD!!");
}
}
```

When calling `updateSQL` the console prints "HELLO WORLD!!"

Is this a bug? Is there a workaround?

Thank you!

[edited]

Answer (score 2):

The description of [`CustomTaskChange`](http://www.liquibase.org/javadoc/liquibase/change/custom/CustomTaskChange.html) says:

```
Interface to implement when creating a custom change that does not actually
generate SQL. If you are updating a database through SQL, 
implementing CustomSqlChange is preferred because the SQL can either 
be executed directly or saved to a text file for later use depending 
on the migration mode used.
```

So use a [`CustomSqlChange`](http://www.liquibase.org/javadoc/liquibase/change/custom/CustomSqlChange.html) instead.

In the `generateStatements()` method you can also print out your sql before you return your `SqlStatement[]` array. 
The println will run every time. But the statements you created will not be applied to the database but instead just be printed to std out when you choose to run it with `updateSQL`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Maybe I didn't make it clear enough...

I actually want a Java method to run on `update`, the class `HelloWorldUpdate` above is just a toy example. The actual `CustomSqlChange` should update a column based on a calculation in the program. But it is part of a database refactoring.

Comment: When calling `updateSQL` I would expect LB to preview the SQL for a CustomSqlChange but to do nothing for a CustomTaskChange. Why would it execute the task, if its just previewing the DB-operation?

Comment: `updateSQL` is for writing the changes that liquibase will do to a file instead of the database. Then you can preview the file (as one use case) and see what liquibase would have executed.

Comment: Right, I want to use it as a preview. But this goes wrong with CustomTaskChange. CustomSqlChange doesn't help either, since it doesn't know whether it runs in update or updateSQL mode. I think, the CustomXXXChanges should receive a parameter in which mode they are running.