# Liquibase-Add a column to all tables containing a specified sufifix in the name

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, migration, liquibase

I want to add a migration to my Spring-Boot project. In this migration I intend to add a column to all the tables which name contains some suffix. I will leave an example below:

In my database I have this two tables `saft_2020_1_111_nc_generalledgerentriestotals` and `saft_2017_2_112_nc_generalledgerentriestotals` and their names both end in `generalledgerentriestotals`.

Is there any way I can make my migration add the column to both the tables?

I am using liquibase to manage the migrations and my database is MySQL.

I tried this way but an exception was thrown because there is no table with that name

```
<databaseChangeLog
        xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
      http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.8.xsd">
 
    <changeSet author="fabio" id="changelog-4.0">
        <addColumn tableName="*_generalledgerentriestotals">
            <column name="multiple_added" type="varchar(255)"/>
        </addColumn>
        <rollback>
            <dropColumn tableName="*_generalledgerentriestotals">
                <column name="multiple_added" type="varchar(255)"/>
            </dropColumn>
        </rollback>
    </changeSet>
 
</databaseChangeLog>
```

Answer (score 1):

Liquibase doesn't work like this. In my opinion this would be dangerous because you are not controlling exactly what you want. Instead of that I would prepare changes with some script for exact tables and put that script into liquibase.

Maybe this can help you

```sql
SELECT table_schema, table_name, 
concat('<changeSet author="fabio" id="',UUID(),'">', '<addColumn tableName="', table_name,'">', '<column name="multiple_added" type="varchar(255)"/>','</changeSet>') as changeset
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables
where table_name like '%_generalledgerentriestotals'
```

Comment: I tried to make that with the like keyword. Sorry for the ignorance but that script in you answer is a SQL file right? Just to make sure  . This task is really killing me

Comment: No it's not sql file. It's plain sql and you have to execute it against your database and then put generated sql files to your changelog. You can try it for example [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b8940d/1)

Comment: Would this work with a custom task?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24080892/customtaskchange-gets-actually-executed-when-called-updatesql

Comment: Runned your file and it returned me 3 tables. Do I have to create a xml with the migration for each one?

Comment: probably yes. but why do you need to do this dynamically? Isn't it just enough to prepare changeSets by the sql I've posted and put them to changelog that will be executed by liquibase?

Comment: you can put the rows of column `changeset` to changelog (xml) and that should be enough.

Comment: the objective of the task is to do dinamically, because there could be like 100 tables ending in that substring. Updating them all manually would take a long time

Comment: Again, that's not how it should work. Imagine that you are going to update 100 tables, and 20th fails for some reason. Then it's trying to rollback, but not all tables at this moment have column that had to be created. So you have an issue where you can't easily move forward nor backward.

Comment: so I can just make a xml file, copy all the generated changesets, and in the main file include it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229300/discussion-between-bilak-and-fabio).